# Is there a way to highlight current column VisualStudio 2012 code editor?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I would like something like thin pale whole-window-long lines to be drawn at the cursor position both for vertical and horizontal position indication. Kind of like this:

[image]

There is already a horizontal line of a sort but no vertical one.

Do you happen to know a decent way to add this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Ident Guides" extension (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e792686d-542b-474a-8c55-630980e72c30), I think.

Comment: I couldn't find a column highlight for the current caret position in this extension? Could you elaborate how to configure it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at [this extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/da227a0b-0e31-4a11-8f6b-3a149cf2e459).

Answer (score 1):

This was also something that i was looking for at VS Code since i was very much used to [Atom's highlight-column](https://atom.io/packages/highlight-column) extension.

There seems to be no dynamic vertical guides which follows the cursor except for this [cursoruler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=freakone.cursoruler) extension. Not super cool but seems to work for me.